# Rake db:test:prepare in Rails 3 app fails with file not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake

I'm not sure why this is happening all of a sudden. I'd like to know how to resolve, please, if anyone else has run into this before or has ideas on where to look. Using bundle exec does not fix, has the same behavior.

rake version 0.9.2.2
rails version 3.2.1
rspec version 2.8.0

```
rake db:test:prepare --trace
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:test:load_schema (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge 
** Execute db:test:load_schema
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:load
/Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:167:in `block in     non_options': file not found: db:test:prepare (ArgumentError)
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:146:in `map!'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:146:in `non_options'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:207:in `non_options'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:52:in `process_args'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:891:in `_run'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:884:in `run'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:21:in `run'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:326:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:27:in `run_once'
from /Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:325:in `block in autorun'
```

and here's my rake -T

```
→ rake -T
rake about                             # List versions of all Rails frameworks and          the environment
rake assets:clean                      # Remove compiled assets
rake assets:precompile                 # Compile all the assets named in          config.assets.precompile
rake bourbon:install[sass_path]        # Move files to the Rails assets directory.
rake clean                             # Remove any temporary products.
rake clobber                           # Remove any generated file.
rake cucumber                          # Alias for cucumber:ok
rake cucumber:all                      # Run all features
rake cucumber:ok                       # Run features that should pass
rake cucumber:rerun                    # Record failing features and run only them if any exist
rake cucumber:wip                      # Run features that are being worked on
rake db:create                         # Create the database from config/database.yml for the current Rails.env (use db:crea...
rake db:database_dump                  # Dump the current database to a MySQL file
rake db:drop                           # Drops the database for the current Rails.env (use db:drop:all to drop all databases)
rake db:fixtures:load                  # Load fixtures into the current environment's database.
rake db:migrate                        # Migrate the database (options: VERSION=x, VERBOSE=false).
rake db:migrate:projects               # Migrates Projects
rake db:migrate:status                 # Display status of migrations
rake db:rollback                       # Rolls the schema back to the previous version (specify steps w/ STEP=n).
rake db:schema:dump                    # Create a db/schema.rb file that can be portably used against any DB supported by AR
rake db:schema:load                    # Load a schema.rb file into the database
rake db:seed                           # Load the seed data from db/seeds.rb
rake db:setup                          # Create the database, load the schema, and initialize with the seed data (use db:res...
rake db:structure:dump                 # Dump the database structure to db/structure.sql. Specify another file with DB_STRUC...
rake db:version                        # Retrieves the current schema version number
rake doc:app                           # Generate docs for the app -- also available doc:rails, doc:guides, doc:plugins (opt...
rake log:clear                         # Truncates all *.log files in log/ to zero bytes
rake middleware                        # Prints out your Rack middleware stack
rake notes                             # Enumerate all annotations (use notes:optimize, :fixme, :todo for focus)
rake notes:custom                      # Enumerate a custom annotation, specify with ANNOTATION=CUSTOM
rake paperclip:clean                   # Cleans out invalid attachments.
rake paperclip:refresh                 # Refreshes both metadata and thumbnails.
rake paperclip:refresh:metadata        # Regenerates content_type/size metadata for a given CLASS (and optional ATTACHMENT).
rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles  # Regenerates missing thumbnail styles for all classes using Paperclip.
rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails      # Regenerates thumbnails for a given CLASS (and optional ATTACHMENT and STYLES splitt...
rake rails:template                    # Applies the template supplied by LOCATION=(/path/to/template) or URL
rake rails:update                      # Update configs and some other initially generated files (or use just update:configs...
rake routes                            # Print out all defined routes in match order, with names.
rake secret                            # Generate a cryptographically secure secret key (this is typically used to generate ...
rake simplecov                         # Run tests for simplecov
rake spec                              # Run all specs in spec directory (excluding plugin specs)
rake spec:controllers                  # Run the code examples in spec/controllers
rake spec:helpers                      # Run the code examples in spec/helpers
rake spec:lib                          # Run the code examples in spec/lib
rake spec:mailers                      # Run the code examples in spec/mailers
rake spec:models                       # Run the code examples in spec/models
rake spec:rcov                         # Run all specs with rcov
rake spec:requests                     # Run the code examples in spec/requests
rake spec:routing                      # Run the code examples in spec/routing
rake spec:views                        # Run the code examples in spec/views
rake stats                             # Report code statistics (KLOCs, etc) from the application
rake test                              # Runs test:units, test:functionals, test:integration together (also available: test:...
rake test:recent                       # Run tests for {:recent=>"test:prepare"} / Test recent changes
rake test:single                       # Run tests for {:single=>"test:prepare"}
rake test:uncommitted                  # Run tests for {:uncommitted=>"test:prepare"} / Test changes since last checkin (onl...
rake time:zones:all                    # Displays all time zones, also available: time:zones:us, time:zones:local -- filter ...
rake tmp:clear                         # Clear session, cache, and socket files from tmp/ (narrow w/ tmp:sessions:clear, tmp...
rake tmp:create                        # Creates tmp directories for sessions, cache, sockets, and pids
Run options: 

# Running tests:



Finished tests in 0.000395s, 0.0000 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: also now rake db:migrate is failing with a similar error

Comment: ok, rake db:migrate:status works, but I still get a similar error at the end.

Comment: `gem update` fixed mine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what happens when something (a gem, for instance), has a line that does something as simple as this:

```
require 'test/unit'
```

This file [has an `at_exit` hook](https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit/blob/99d13bda8bb1ff7729b23736db1adbff47e09ff1/lib/test/unit.rb#L324-328) which will automatically attempt to run tests, using the last "phrase" in your command as the name of the test which to run. This is why it reports `db:test:prepare` can't be found.

For instance, the `shoulda-context` gem does this. We were using it in Spree and got the same problem as you. I opened a [pull request to fix this issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-context/pull/4).

Comment: Sorry, struggling to connect the dots this morning. What did you end up doing? Forking shoulda-context and requiring your repo in your Gemfile?

Comment: I stopped using shoulda-context.

Comment: Since shoulda-context is currently required in the gemspec for shoulda, I had to fork shoulda-context and make the patch you suggested above. If you know a better way, I'd love to know.

Comment: Read assanghi comment on github: add ```gem 'test-unit', :require => "test/unit"``` to Gemfile, it works.

Comment: Only including `gem 'shoulda-matchers'` (if you don't actually use shoulda-context) will also fix this. https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/issues/51#issuecomment-4571082

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'shoulda-context', require: false
```

test_helper.rb:

```
require 'shoulda-context'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a non-useful path, but have you changed anything in your dev environment recently? Like changing XCode? I was getting all kinds of strange things going on until I rebuilt with the osx-gcc-installer.

Honestly, this seems like something outside of just a gem being broken, but I couldn't explain many of my errors either.

Comment: Nothing new. Just in case I uninstalled Xcode and imploded RVM, rebooted, installed osx-gcc-installer, and a fresh rvm copy of 1.9.3 and I'm still getting the error. Must be something in my app somewhere.

Comment: And, I'm getting the same problem on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce a very similar error under different circumstances (outside rails):

- MRI 1.9.3-p125
- Rake 0.9.2
- Rakefile: `Rake::TestTask.new`
- test/test_foo.rb: `require "test/unit"`

(complains test/test*.rb not found, same stack)

Workarounds:

- Upgrade to Rake 0.9.2.2
- Downgrade to MRI 1.9.3-p0
- Upgrade to test/unit 2.x https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit

Given this, perhaps take a second look at rake. In particular if using bundler, try `bundler exec rake ...` rather than just `rake ...`?

Comment: Thanks, but I did say in the original question using bundle exec made no difference. Are you using shoulda? See Ryan's answer.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your note on bundle exec. Shoulda was not required to reproduce my suspiciously similar error as above (just rake, test-unit and MRI1.9.3-p125). 

I still don't understood why but I'm unlikely to pursue this further given "gem install rake" fixes things for me. Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding a "gem 'test-unit'" line to my Gemfile